# DB2 - Reclaiming disk space used by dropped tables

Tags: database, db2, relational-database

I have an application that logs to a DB2 database. Each log is stored in a daily table, meaning that I have several tables, one per each day.

Since the application is running for quite some time, I dropped some of the older daily tables, but the disk space was not reclaimed.

I understand this is normal in DB2, so I goggled and found out that the following command can be used to reclaim space:

```
db2 alter tablespace <table space> reduce max
```

Since the tablespace that store the daily log tables is called **USERSPACE1**, I executed the following command successfully:

```
db2 alter tablespace userspace1 reduce max
```

Unfortunately the disk space used by DB2 instance is still the same...

I've read somewhere that the **REORG** command can be executed, but what I've seen it is used to reorganize tables. Since I dropped the tables, how can I use **REORG**?

Is there any other way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: The answer depends on the DB2 version and the type of tablespace where your tables were.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry guys,

The command that I mentioned on the original post works after all, but the space was retrieved very slowly.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Reduce the size of a tablespace is very complex. The extents (set of contiguous pages; unit of tablespace allocation) of the tables are not distributed sequentially for a same table. When you reorg a table, the rows will be organized in pages, and the new pages will be written normally at the end of the tablespace. Sometimes, the high watermark will be increased, and your tablespace will be bigger.

You need to reorg all tables from a tablespace in order to "defrag" all tables. Then, you have to perform a new reorg in order to use the previous space, because it should be an empty space in the tablespace.

However, there are many criteria that impacts the organization of the tables in a tablespace: New extents are created (new rows, rows overflow due to updates); compression  could be activated after reorg.

What you can do is to assign few or just one table per tablespace; however, you will waste a lot of space (overhead, empty pages, etc.)

The command that you are using is an automatic way to do that, but it does not always work as desired: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0055392.html

If you want to see the distribution of the tables in your tablespace, you can use [db2dart](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0003477.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F3-6-2-6-38). Then, you can have an idea of which table to reorg (move).